# Select last row

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

Please how can I retrieve the last on an Android DB? I'm using the Sugar ORM library to abstract all db operation but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to retrieve the oldest record on the db.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to order by some timestamp, if you have it, or by the ID, if it is autoincrementing, and take only the first result:

```java
Thing.find(Thing.class, null, null, null, "timestamp DESC", "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm is

```
Get a list of all objects from the database
Take the one with the "maximum" date
```

I'm unfamiliar with Sugar ORM, so I don't know how to do this with that particular library other than coding it myself. The SQL query for this would be fairly straight forward.

Comment: I just thought about it. I could also get the list of all objects as you have suggested and order the id in ascending order and limit to one. Is this efficient?

Comment: @MrSmith Sorting a list is O(n*log(n)). Compare this to a linear search to find the maximum which is O(n). So, no, sorting is not efficient.